# I have this compilation error:

Tags: arduino-uno

C:\Users\MGMCETIT\Desktop\Dumpster\Dumpster.ino: In function 'void loop()':

C:\Users\MGMCETIT\Desktop\Dumpster\Dumpster.ino:40:28: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

```
 if(esp8266.find("+IPD,"))

                        ^
```

Comment: did you write the `esp8266.find` function? if you did, that's a simple fix - though, that's just a warning isn't it? the code still compiles

Comment: @JaromandaX it is core Stream class. it is only a warning

Comment: I did notice it's just a warning :p @Juraj

Comment: It appears Arduino decided that it would be a good idea to use `char *` instead of `const char *` for functions that don't modify the parameter. It should always be `const char *` unless you have a good reason not to.  Silly Arduino.

Comment: I have submitted a bug report (gently) berating them.

Comment: @Majenko, it is there 8 years. commit comment: "This from Michael's TextFinder library, incorporated into the Stream class: find(), findUntil(), parseInt(), parseFloat(), readChars(), readCharsUntil(), readCharsBetween(), setTimeout()."